# How to change SizeMode of a rectangle in a picturebox?

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox, zooming

In VB2010 I try to change the **SizeMode** of my **PictureBox** that my image fits into it. The problem is that **SizeMode** has no effect when I change the value to **Zoom** or **StretchImage**. For some reason the size of my image is locked.

My code looks like this:

```
    void frameCallBack(IntPtr lpUserData, ref VCECLB_FrameInfoEx frameInfo)
    {

        if (frameInfo.dma_status != 0) return;
        // fill image

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);


        BitmapData bmdata = image.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image.PixelFormat);

        UInt32 outputBitDepth;
        IntPtr stride = new IntPtr(bmdata.Stride);

        VCECLB_Error err = NativeFunctions.VCECLB_UnpackRawPixelsEx(ref pRawPixelInfo, frameInfo.lpRawBuffer, bmdata.Scan0, ref stride, VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_TopDown | VCECLB_Output_Format.VCECLB_EX_FMT_3Channel, out outputBitDepth);

        image.UnlockBits(bmdata);

        preview.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        preview.Image = new Bitmap(image);        
    }
```

The image in the PictureBox is shrinked and has a large black stripe on the right side. It looks like this:
[image]

The same image should look like this:
[image]

Question:
How can I resize my image automatically that it fits my PictureBox?

Thanks!

Comment: to make image fit picture box control the size mode is to be set centre image.so for resizing `preview.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage`

Comment: does not work with "CenterImage". The problem is that my image is larger than the PictureBox. I do not see the full image.

Comment: To fully understand the problem I updated the question with two images!

Comment: StretchImage should work.  You tagged your post VB.Net but you posted c# code.  Try commenting out the LockBits stuff and try just getting the image to work right first.

Comment: @LarsTech When I use StretchImage it works only in vertical way. This means I still have the black frame on the right side. To which LockBits are you refering to?

Comment: I don't see the same problem.  The c# code you posted is performing a LockBits operation on your image.  My *guess* is your LockBit operation is changing the image and causing a black edge to be added to the image.  Maybe the DPI settings are affecting it.  Something, because StretchImage should work in both horizontal and vertical stretching.  Try doing a save operation on the image with the black edge, see if the black edge is there in an image editor.  If so, your image was changed.

Comment: @LarsTech I saved the image and the black edge is also there. Is there a way to avoid the LockBit opeartion to see if the image works?

Comment: What I can say is, that the black edge is 2/3 and the image on the left is 1/3 of the whole!

Comment: When I change the image-width like this:
    image = new Bitmap((int)(pRawPixelInfo.cameraData.Width/3), (int)pRawPixelInfo.cameraData.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

then I get three identical images without a black edge on the side. If I divide the image-width by 2 than I get two identical images (50% of the whole) and 50% is the black edge.

Comment: The solution is to change the Image-Format to 8bit and change the RGB index to have a full image.